# как запустить на ios 2GIS и Yandex navigator используя библиотеку url_launcher?

Tags: flutter, dart

на android запусткается, но на ios не запускается, вот мой код:

```
Future<void> _launch2GIS({String lat, String lng}) async {
    if (await canLaunch('dgis://')) {
      final bool nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launch(
        "dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/" + "$lng" + "," + "$lat",
        forceSafariVC: Platform.isIOS ? true : false,
        universalLinksOnly: Platform.isIOS ? false : true,
      );
      if (!nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          await launch(
            'market://details?id=ru.dublgis.dgismobile',
            forceSafariVC: Platform.isIOS ? true : false,
            universalLinksOnly: Platform.isIOS ? false : true,
          );
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          await launch(
            'https://apps.apple.com/kz/app/2gis-maps-navigation/id481627348',
            forceSafariVC: Platform.isIOS ? true : false,
            universalLinksOnly: Platform.isIOS ? false : true,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

подскажите как правильно написать код, чтобы запускался и на андроид и на ios, и если нет данного приложения в смартфоне то на ios кидать в app store а на android в google play с этим приложением

Answer (score 0):

У обоих платформ ограниченный набор возможностей URL Schemes: [IOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html), [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html). По этому будет легче открывать веб версию сторов.